# Настройка php.ini (вывод ошибок) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, php.ini

имеем:    `PHP 7.2.25-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2019 07:41:59) ( NTS )`

правлю:

```
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

и

```
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

раскомментирываю:

```
display_errors = On
```

и

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

перезапускаю apache2 `systemctl restart apache2` но ничего не происходит

Умышленно пропускаю `;` в конце строки рабочего скрипта а страница просто отображает `HTTP ERROR 500` не указывая на ошибку.

Подскажите, что нужно сделать чтобы скрипты отображали ошибки?

Comment: раскомментирываю:....  скорее всего там ниже есть еще одна строчка уже "раскомментированная" в которой стоит display_errors = Off которую и надо было поправить. И вообще в апаче есть на сколько я помню подключение php как модуль или как fpm, cgi... надо для начала понять как именно подключен ваш php. Вариант как модуль соответсвенно должен присутсвовать файл php7.2.conf в mods-enabled. Это надо для того чтобы понимать в каком именно файле php.ini надо править.

Comment: @biniz Действительно была строчка ниже, спасибо!